# best way to monitor for changes on database

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle

I need to make a web application in java, that offers a dashboard based on the content of a db table.
It needs to be "autorefreshing", and always syncronized with the actual data in the db.

For the browser <-> servlet interaction I can use websockets or at least long polling to achieve the "freshness", but I'm stuck with the java <-> db communication.

I can have some polling, but I would really have some "notification" from the db itself.

Is there some way / some library to achieve?

For my case the db is oracle, but I'm interested also in solution for postgres.

Comment: If it is an option for you, then create one job in DB which finds the difference in the previously sent and current data and if it finds any difference call the soap service using PL/SQL

Comment: I haven't used this complex functionality, but in theory this situation is precisely what [Continuous Query Notification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adfns/cqn.html#GUID-373BAF72-3E63-42FE-8BEA-8A2AEFBF1C35) was built for.

Comment: @JonHeller this seems useful, I never knew about it; thanks

Answer (score 0):

To monitor db changes debezium connector is good. By using this u will get every change event of database in kafka topics.

For oracle look at [this](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/oracle.html) tutorial

For postgresql look at [this](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.1/connectors/postgresql.html) tutorial